# TensorFlow - What is random_crop doing in Cifar10 example?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, tensorflow

In the Cifar10 example in the TensorFlow examples they are distorting the images with a random combination of cropping, flipping, brightening, contrasting, and whitening. This concept makes sense except the cropping seems a little odd to me. The images will need to be the same dimensions for the network and the cropping code looks like this:

```
  height = IMAGE_SIZE
  width = IMAGE_SIZE

  # Image processing for training the network. Note the many random
  # distortions applied to the image.

  # Randomly crop a [height, width] section of the image.
  distorted_image = tf.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width, 3])
```

Since the height and width are based on the image size is this actually doing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, `IMAGE_SIZE` is set to `24`. So basically what this code does is select a randomly chosen offset and extracts a `24 X 24` patch. It probably ensures that the offset is chosen in a way that the patch can be extracted without any wrap around or other weird boundary condition or maybe it pads it (should be easy to check).

I guess `IMAGE_SIZE` could be better named as `PATCH_SIZE` or something. Note the original CIFAR 10 input image is `32 x 32`

Comment: @bradden_gross Glad to have been able to help!